# Is it possible to remove 'checkmark' on unselectable rows

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

We are using ui-grid v3.1.1 and have a specific use-case where a grid needs to have certain rows selectable, and others not selectable, depending on the code of a specific cell in the row. We have been implementing the grid's html as:

```
<div id="gridSummary" ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid-summary" ui-grid-auto-resize ui-grid-selection ui-grid-tree-view ui-grid-pinning>
        <div class="grid-empty" ng-show="!gridOptions.data.length">No Corresponding Data Found</div>
</div>
```

and have been experimenting with the isRowSelectable gridOption which does what we want except for one issue: we don't want the disabled checkmark icon to appear on the non-selectable rows. Is there a way of causing the checkmark to be hidden/collapsed when the row is not selectable?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by changing the `rowHeaderIcon` for non selectable rows.

You can override the template for the selection row header button and add custom css. Inject `templateCache` in your controller and override the template like this.

```
$templateCache.put('ui-grid/selectionRowHeaderButtons',
    "<div class=\"ui-grid-selection-row-header-buttons\" ng-class=\"{'ui-grid-row-selected': row.isSelected , 'ui-grid-icon-cancel':!grid.appScope.isSelectable(row.entity), 'ui-grid-icon-ok':grid.appScope.isSelectable(row.entity)}\" ng-click=\"selectButtonClick(row, $event)\">&nbsp;</div>"
  );
```

The template will use a method in your controller scope to identify if the row is selectable.

Found this useful [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vaqBY235Lfz7WLvy0FCc?p=preview).

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks so much for this. Works a charm.

Answer (score 0):

[I'd like to propose this Plunker which has no icon at all for unselectable rows](http://plnkr.co/edit/kN1skH?p=preview)

```
  $templateCache.put('ui-grid/selectionRowHeaderButtons',
    "<div ng-class=\"{'ui-grid-selection-row-header-buttons': grid.appScope.isSelectable(row), 'ui-grid-icon-ok' : grid.appScope.isSelectable(row), 'ui-grid-row-selected': row.isSelected}\" ng-click=\"selectButtonClick(row, $event)\">&nbsp;</div>"
  );
```